# How can I send SMS without open/launch the Application service in Palm WebOS?

Tags: webos, palm

I am sending SMS in palm webOS by launching or opening the messaging application service. Sample code is here:

```
this.controller.serviceRequest("palm://com.palm.applicationManager", {
             method : 'open',
             parameters: {
                           id: 'com.palm.app.messaging',
                           params: {
                                     sms:'9848012345',
                                     messageText: 'This is the message.'
                                   }

                         } 

           });
```

Can I send that SMS without open/launch messaging application service? Any one please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that would allow unseen spam messages to be pervasive throughout webOS apps which is soemthing HP/Palm does not want.